# Audio/video streaming is out of sync after a random period of time

Tags: ffmpeg, sync, streaming, flv

I'm using the NodeMediaServer, a stream server developed in NodeJS, with FLV and FFmpeg, it work very well but after a random period of time the audio/video streaming is out of sync and I don't know why.

I'm using FFmpeg to brodcast the audio/video stream to NodeMediaServer and below is the FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -r 30 -s 640x480 -threads 0 -pixel_format yuv420p -i video=%videoCardName%:audio=%audioCapture% -f webm -aspect 16:9 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -c:v libx264 -pixel_format yuv420p -b:v 1M -threads 0 -fflags nobuffer -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -af aresample=async=1 -f flv rtmp://%streamingAddress%
```

My system has the following features:

- Windows Server 2016
- RAM 64 GB
- CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4214R CPU @ 2.40GHz (2 processors)
- Disk SSD M2 400GB

thank you in advance for the reply and any advice.

Comment: Are you streaming an already recorded video? Is that in sync all the way through?

Comment: Thank you @DavidPostill for your reply, you ask me if I recorded video for hours and if that is sync? I recorded video for minutes, but no for hours, because I usually the audio/video streaming is out of sync after hours and for a few tenths. I will try that and I'll let you know.

Comment: I am streaming from capture cards @DavidPostill